# Validation on modal dialog forms

Tags: forms

I opened my form in a jQuery modal dialog using the [Simple Dialog](http://drupal.org/project/simple_dialog) module. I am unable to do any sort of validations on it.
Is it a limitation of the module? Would it validate if I use any other method of creating a  modal dialog form, such as using a CTools modal dialog, or using the Drupal overlay?

Comment: Hi I have the same problem with Simple Dialog module. I can display my form into Simple dialog window, but after validation, I see the answer (error messages or validation message) in Drupal page et not inside the Simple Dialog window.
Any Help ? and for Ctools solution, how can I do it ? any tutorial ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: yeah there is an example that comes with ctools module. you can see the test page on how to use ctools popup modals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the [Chaos tool suite](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) module, and it does that!